# Deleting content of every string after first empty space

Tags: java, string

How can I delete everything after first empty space in a string which user selects? I was reading this [how to remove some words from a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186066/how-to-remove-some-words-from-a-string-in-java). Can this help me in my case?

Comment: By "empty space" do you just mean the space character, or other whitespace?

Comment: Do you mean extracting the first word from a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is no space in the beginning of the string.
Follow these steps-

1. Split the string at space. It will create an array.
2. Get the first element of that array.

Hope this helps.

```
str = "Example string"
String[] _arr = str.split("\\s");
String word = _arr[0];
```

You need to consider multiple white spaces and space in the beginning before considering the above code.

I am not native to JAVA Programming but have an idea that it has split function for string.
And the reference you cited in the question is bit complex, while you can achieve the desired thing very easily.

**P.S.** In future if you make a mind to get two words or three, splitting method is better (assuming you have already dealt with multiple white-spaces) else substring is better.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replaceAll` with a regex `\s.*` which match every thing after space:

```
String str = "Hello java word!";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s.*", "");
```

**output**

```
Hello
```

## regex demo

---

Like @Coffeehouse Coder mention in comment, This solution will replace every thing if the input start with space, so if you want to avoid this case, you can trim your input using `string.trim()` so it can remove the spaces in start and in end.

Comment: Don't forget to trim the string.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder no need, because the space also will be replaced :)

Comment: What about the space at the starting, if any?

Comment: it will be replace every thing in this case @CoffeehouseCoder the op said `after first empty space`

Answer (score 2):

```
// Taking 'str' as your string
// To remove the first space(s) of the string, 
str = str.trim();
int index = str.indexOf(" ");
String word = str.substring(0, index);
```

This is just one method of many.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); // This replaces one or more spaces with one space
String[] words = str.split("\\s");
String first = words[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it can be:

```
System.out.println("Hello world!".split(" ")[0]);
```

Comment: What do I need to do to delete before the first space? Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in my opinion would be to just locate the index which the user wants it to be cut off at and then call the substring() method from 0 to the index they wanted.  Set that = to a new string and you have the string they want.

If you want to replace the string then just set the original string = to the result of the substring() method.

Link to substring() method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Comment: Locate substring and then get the substring? This method may be faster than splitting.

Comment: I think it should be.  It takes almost no parsing energy and uses one method.  splitting takes more time and space.

Comment: Splitting will help to get two words in case needed. So splitting is flexible than your current method.

Comment: Fair, but I just answer bases off of what I am given and if you don't need flexibility then might as well take the easy route.

Comment: My approach is lazy one, so that it encompasses the future things.

Answer (score 1):

There are already 5 perfectly good answers, so let me add a sixth one. Variety is the spice of life!

```
private static final Pattern FIRST_WORD = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

public static String firstWord(CharSequence text) {
    Matcher m = FIRST_WORD.matcher(text);
    return m.find() ? m.group() : "";
}
```

Advantages over the `.split(...)[0]`-type answers:

1. It directly does exactly what is being asked, i.e. "Find the first sequence of non-space characters." So the self-documentation is more explicit.
2. It is more efficient when called on multiple strings (e.g. for batch processing a large list of strings) because the regular expression is compiled only once.
3. It is more space-efficient because it avoids unnecessarily creating a whole array with references to each word when we only need the first.
4. It works without having to trim the string.

(I know this is probably too late to be of any use to the OP but I'm leaving it here as an alternative solution for future readers.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be more efficient

```
    String str = "Hello world!";
    int spaceInd = str.indexOf(' ');
    if(spaceInd != -1) {
        str = str.substring(0, spaceInd);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("[%s]", str));
```